# ¿Cómo pasar parametros de un fragment a un DialogFragment en kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, textview, dialog-fragment

alguien me podría asesorar sobre como puedo pasar variables a un DialogFragment desde un Fragment, estas variables las voy a utilizar para introducirlas como texto en los TextView del DialogFragment.

El fragment (los parametros del método transacción los quiero mandar al dialogFragment):

```
override fun transaccion(transaccion: String, contract: String, hash: String) {
  
        detallesAddress().show(childFragmentManager, "detallesAddress")

    }
```

El dialog Fragment:

```
class detallesAddress() : DialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentDetallesAddressBinding?= null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.round_corner)
        _binding = FragmentDetallesAddressBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val width = (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.90).toInt()
        val height = (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.60).toInt()
        dialog!!.window?.setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías acompañar tu pregunta con el código en el que intentas aplicar esto.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @Alexci ya está el código que tengo hasta ahora, lo que necesito es mandar los parametros de la función transaccion  al dialog fragment para poder aplicarlos a TextViews antes de mostrar el dialogFragment en una ventana flotante